# Everything in one slide for a theme

Tags: beamer

I have the following problem. I use a theme, where it seems, that I can't put everything in one slide. First, there is an empty page, than the picture, than then every item one after another. I want to have a picture on the left side and the text on the right side to appear at once in one slide. Is there a way to do it with the following code?

I use the FUBerlin theme, which you can find here: 
http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/pkg/beamer-fuberlin.html

```
\documentclass[t,smaller,compress]{FUbeamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{Anonymous \\
 Betreuer: Dr. Anonymous}
\date{1. Juli 2014}
\titlegraphic{geo}
\fachbereich{Institut}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Motivation}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
     \begin{column}[T]{5cm}
        pic
        \includegraphics[height=6cm]{region_krueg.jpg}
        \end{column}    
        \begin{column}[T]{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\item text
\item text 
\item text
\item text
\end{itemize}

   \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
     \begin{column}[T]{5cm}
        %Bild
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{verteilung_kor.jpg}
        \end{column}    
        \begin{column}[T]{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{itemize}

   \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If it isn't possible with this theme, could somebody give me an alternative theme, where it works? Help is much appreciated. It's my first presentation in beamer.

Greetz

Comment: If you think an answer resolved you problem, just click on the `V` and it'll be marked as solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the `FUbeamer.cls` and to stop the one-by-one display of the listed items, it's very simple...

You just have to comment the `line 69` of the `FUbeamer.cls` file.

It's this line : `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+-| alert@+>}`

It specify the default imetize parameters...

By commenting it, you just refer back to the classical method, everything on 1 slide.

I hope it helped